# rails, is there a way to make this query in rails runner run faster?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am chaining thousands of query's like this one in a rails runner file. Each query takes 8-10 seconds using PostgreSQL in a 2 million record DB.

```
Model.where(name: 'peter').where(is_active: true).where('n1=? OR n2=? OR n3=? OR n4=? OR n5=?', @d01_1, @d01_1, @d01_1, @d01_1, @d01_1).where('n1=? OR n2=? OR n3=? OR n4=? OR n5=?', @d01_2, @d01_2, @d01_2, @d01_2, @d01_2).where('n1=? OR n2=? OR n3=? OR n4=? OR n5=?', @d01_3, @d01_3, @d01_3, @d01_3, @d01_3).where('n1=? OR n2=? OR n3=? OR n4=? OR n5=?', @d01_4, @d01_4, @d01_4, @d01_4, @d01_4).update_all(is_active: false)
```

in this query I am searching for records containing a combination of 4 numbers in the model attributes n1,n2,n3,n4,n5 and updating the record.

This runner takes currently 3-4 days to complete. 
Any ideas on how to reduce this time?

EDIT: 
Example:

```
@d01_1=1

 id:1 (n1:1 n2:2 n3:3 n4:4 n5:5 is_active:true)
 id:2 (n1:2 n2:3 n3:1 n4:4 n5:5 is_active:true)
 id:3 (n1:10 n2:2 n3:3 n4:1 n5:5 is_active:true)
 id:4 (n1:7 n2:2 n3:3 n4:4 n5:1 is_active:true)
 id:5 (n1:8 n2:2 n3:3 n4:4 n5:5 is_active:true)
```

Find ids where some attribute contains @d01_1 "the number 1" and update :is_active=>false

Table schema:

```
create_table "modelname", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string  "name"
t.integer  "n1"
t.integer  "n2"
t.integer  "n3"
t.integer  "n4"
t.integer  "n5"
t.integer  "n6"
t.integer  "n7"
t.integer  "n8"
t.integer  "n9"
t.integer  "n10"
t.integer  "n11"
t.integer  "n12"
t.integer  "n13"
t.integer  "n14"
t.integer  "n15"
t.boolean  "is_active",           default: true
t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
 end
```

Comment: I don't understand what this query is suppose to do, it seems very deficient with all this `OR`s . Please explain (if possible show the select this query generates) this query better.

Comment: Where are you with indexing?

Comment: Not indexing. How do you think  I could/should index for this example? tks

Comment: Can you provide a table schema? we could then advise

Comment: some questions... Is this table updated or inserted to frequently? does the table have a primary key? Ideally you will have a unique index somewhere in this table if not then there are a range of possibilities - create a unique index, create a single column index, or create a compound key index (multi field index) any data item used frequently in a where clause should have an index really - see following resource: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_indexes.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link.I am not currently inserting records very frequently though my searches .where() include most attibutes of the table. Ill probaly try to create an index for each column to see if it improves.....

Comment: No problem its important to note that the more indexes you have on a table, the slower INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations will be. This is why adding indexes for performance is a trade off, and all about balance. in this table is there a combination of fields that is unique? or one column  unique? if so this would server well as a primary key and will be indexed for you